# Ionic Angular custom fonts not begin loaded

Tags: css, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, fonts

### The Problem

No matter what i do, there is no way to make iOS Simulator load the custom fonts.

I've tested everything I've found across different Ionic versions and all platforms and the current setup works perfectly in `Google Chrome Browser`, `Safari Browser`, `Android Device` and `Android Emulator` but not in `iOS Simulator` (could not test it in `iOS Device` since i don't have one yet).

#### Expected Behavior

[image]

#### Current Behavior

No custom font dependent component is shown except when commenting its font styling (second image).
[image]
[image]

#### Code

- Angular-Ionic mandatory `global.scss` (with repeated styling just to test if its correctly loaded only from certain sources)

```
// http://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/
@import '~@ionic/angular/css/core.css';
@import '~@ionic/angular/css/normalize.css';
@import '~@ionic/angular/css/structure.css';
@import '~@ionic/angular/css/typography.css';

@import '~@ionic/angular/css/padding.css';
@import '~@ionic/angular/css/float-elements.css';
@import '~@ionic/angular/css/text-alignment.css';
@import '~@ionic/angular/css/text-transformation.css';
@import '~@ionic/angular/css/flex-utils.css';
@import '~animate.css/animate.min';

@font-face {
    font-family: "Gotham";  
    src: local('GothamMedium'), local('GothamMedium'), 
      url('assets/GothamMedium.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
      url('assets/GothamMedium.woff2') format('woff2'),
      url('assets/GothamMedium.woff') format('woff'),
      url('assets/GothamMedium.ttf') format('truetype'),
      url('assets/GothamMedium.svg#GothamMedium') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
  }
  
  @font-face {
    font-family: "Gotham";
    src: local('GothamBold'), local('GothamBold'),
      url('assets/GothamBold.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
      url('assets/GothamBold.woff2') format('woff2'),
      url('assets/GothamBold.woff') format('woff'),
      url('assets/GothamBold.ttf') format('truetype'),
      url('assets/GothamBold.svg#GothamBold') format('svg');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
  }

@mixin font($weight, $size: false, $shadow: false, $align: false) { 
    font-family: "Gotham" !important;
    font-weight: $weight;

    @if $weight==regular {
        @if $shadow {
            text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #aaaa;
        }
    }

    @if $weight==bold {
        @if $shadow {
            text-shadow: 1px 2px 4px #aaaa;
        }
    }

    @if $size {
        font-size: $size !important;
    }

    @if $align {
        text-align: $align !important;
    }

}
//...
/*:root[mode=ios] .gotham,
:root[mode=md] .gotham{
  --ion-font-family:  'Gotham' !important;
  font-family:  'Gotham' !important;
}*/
}

.subtitulo {
    @include font(normal, 3.5vw, false, center);
    margin: auto !important;
}

ion-card-title,
h1 {
    top: -10px;
    @include font(bold, 9vw, true);
    color: var(--ion-color-primary);
}
```

- Ionic mandatory theming `variables.scss`

```
// Ionic Variables and Theming. For more info, please see:
// http://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/

/** Ionic CSS Variables **/


:root {
  // --ion-font-family: "GothamMedium", "Roboto";
  // font-family: var(--ion-font-family) !important;

  --ion-font-family:  'Gotham' !important;
  font-family:  'Gotham' !important;

//... other non-related theming variables
}
```

- Ionic-suggested `fonts.scss` (i was going to deprecate it if the `globals.scss` code block functioned correctly, or the inverse). I do use `mixins` to make styling faster.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Gotham";  
    src: local('GothamMedium'), local('GothamMedium'), 
      url('../assets/GothamMedium.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
      url('../assets/GothamMedium.woff2') format('woff2'),
      url('../assets/GothamMedium.woff') format('woff'),
      url('../assets/GothamMedium.ttf') format('truetype'),
      url('../assets/GothamMedium.svg#GothamMedium') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
  }
  
  @font-face {
    font-family: "Gotham";
    src: local('GothamBold'), local('GothamBold'),
      url('../assets/GothamBold.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
      url('../assets/GothamBold.woff2') format('woff2'),
      url('../assets/GothamBold.woff') format('woff'),
      url('../assets/GothamBold.ttf') format('truetype'),
      url('../assets/GothamBold.svg#GothamBold') format('svg');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
  }

@mixin font($weight, $size: false, $shadow: false, $align: false) { 
    font-family: "Gotham" !important;
    font-weight: $weight;

    @if $weight==regular {
        @if $shadow {
            text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #aaaa;
        }
    }

    @if $weight==bold {
        @if $shadow {
            text-shadow: 1px 2px 4px #aaaa;
        }
    }

    @if $size {
        font-size: $size !important;
    }

    @if $align {
        text-align: $align !important;
    }

}
```

#### Configuration

- `angular.json`

```json
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/src/workspace/workspace-schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "defaultProject": "app",
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "app": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "www",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "src/assets/",
                "output": "assets/"
              },
              {
                "glob": "**/*.woff2",
                "input": "src/assets/",
                "output": "assets/"
              },
              {
                "glob": "**/*.svg",
                "input": "node_modules/ionicons/dist/ionicons/svg",
                "output": "./svg"
              },
              {
                "glob": "**/*.svg",
                "input": "node_modules/ionicons/dist/ionicons/svg",
                "output": "./svg"
              }
            ],
            "styles": [              
              {
                "input": "src/theme/fonts.scss"
              },
              {
                "input": "src/theme/variables.scss"
              },
              {
                "input": "src/global.scss"
              },
//...
```

- `package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "author": "",
  "homepage": "",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "android:dev": "ionic cordova run android --external --debug",
    "android:prod": "ionic cordova run android -l --ssl --external --prod",
    "ios:dev": "ionic cordova run ios --prod",
    "ios:prod": "ionic cordova run ios -l --ssl --external --prod",
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^10.1.5",
    "@angular/core": "^10.1.5",
    "@angular/forms": "^10.1.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^10.1.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^10.1.5",
    "@angular/router": "^10.1.5",
    "@ionic-native/bluetooth-serial": "^5.28.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "5.22.0",
    "@ionic-native/device": "^5.28.0",
    "@ionic-native/diagnostic": "^5.28.0",
    "@ionic-native/firebase-x": "^5.26.0",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^5.26.0",
    "@ionic-native/native-storage": "^5.26.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "5.22.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.22.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^5.0.4",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.2.0",
    "@keyframes/core": "^2.0.10",
    "@teamhive/lottie-player": "^1.0.0",
    "animate.css": "^3.7.2",
    "cordova": "^10.0.0",
    "cordova-android-firebase-gradle-release": "^4.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-bluetooth-serial": "^0.4.7",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-enable-multidex": "^0.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^4.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^5.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-nativestorage": "^2.3.2",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.3",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.4",
    "core-js": "^3.6.4",
    "firebase": "^7.14.5",
    "howler": "^2.1.3",
    "keyframes": "^2.3.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.19",
    "native-run": "^1.0.0",
    "ng-payment-card": "0.0.8",
    "npm-check-updates": "^4.0.4",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.4",
    "zone.js": "^0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "^0.900.5",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1001.6",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^10.1.6",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^10.1.6",
    "@angular/cli": "^10.1.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "^10.1.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^10.1.5",
    "@angular/language-service": "^10.1.5",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^2.2.0",
    "@ionic/lab": "^3.1.6",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.5.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.8",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.149",
    "@types/node": "^13.7.7",
    "codelyzer": "^5.2.1",
    "cordova-android": "^9.0.0",
    "cordova-ios": "^6.1.1",
    "cordova-plugin-androidx": "^2.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter": "^1.1.1",
    "cordova-plugin-firebasex": "10.2.0-cli",
    "jasmine-core": "^3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.2.1",
    "karma": "^4.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^3.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.2",
    "protractor": "^5.4.3",
    "ts-node": "^8.6.2",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.0.3"
  },
  "description": "Crucijuegos Salas App",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-local-notification": {},
      "cordova-plugin-background-mode": {},
      "cordova-plugin-nativestorage": {},
      "cordova-android-firebase-gradle-release": {
        "FIREBASE-CORE": "17.0.0",
        "FIREBASE-ADS": "18.0.0",
        "FIREBASE-ANALYTICS": "17.0.0",
        "FIREBASE-APPINDEXING": "19.0.0",
        "FIREBASE-AUTH": "18.0.0",
        "FIREBASE-FIRESTORE": "20.0.0",
        "FIREBASE-FUNCTIONS": "18.0.0",
        "FIREBASE-MESSAGING": "19.0.0",
        "FIREBASE-STORAGE": "18.0.0",
        "FIREBASE-CRASH": "16.2.1",
        "CRASHLYTICS": "2.10.1",
        "FIREBASE-DYNAMIC-LINKS": "18.0.0",
        "FIREBASE-INVITES": "17.0.0",
        "FIREBASE-INAPPMESSAGING": "18.0.1",
        "FIREBASE-INAPPMESSAGING-DISPLAY": "18.0.1",
        "FIREBASE-ML-VISION": "21.0.0",
        "FIREBASE-ML-VISION-IMAGE-LABEL-MODEL": "18.0.0",
        "FIREBASE-ML-VISION-FACE-MODEL": "18.0.0",
        "FIREBASE-ML-VISION-OBJECT-DETECTION-MODEL": "17.0.0",
        "FIREBASE-ML-NATURAL-LANGUAGE": "20.0.0",
        "FIREBASE-ML-NATURAL-LANGUAGE-LANGUAGE-ID-MODEL": "20.0.0",
        "FIREBASE-ML-NATURAL-LANGUAGE-TRANSLATE-MODEL": "20.0.0",
        "FIREBASE-ML-NATURAL-LANGUAGE-SMART-REPLY-MODEL": "20.0.0",
        "FIREBASE-ML-MODEL-INTERPRETER": "20.0.0",
        "FIREBASE-ML-VISION-AUTOML": "17.0.0",
        "FIREBASE-PERF": "18.0.0",
        "FIREBASE-DATABASE": "18.0.0",
        "FIREBASE-CONFIG": "18.0.0"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-enable-multidex": {},
      "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ble-central": {
        "BLUETOOTH_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": " "
      },
      "cordova-plugin-bluetooth-serial": {},
      "cordova-plugin-firebasex": {
        "FIREBASE_ANALYTICS_COLLECTION_ENABLED": "true",
        "FIREBASE_PERFORMANCE_COLLECTION_ENABLED": "true",
        "FIREBASE_CRASHLYTICS_COLLECTION_ENABLED": "true"
      }
    },
    "platforms": [
      "ios",
      "android"
    ]
  }
}
```

#### Env

- Mac development station

```sh
74-80-245-21:cruci-app user922954$ ionic info

Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.11.12 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.3.3
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.901.12
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 9.1.12
   @angular/cli                  : 9.1.12
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.3.3

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 10.0.0
   Cordova Platforms : ios 6.1.1
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 5.0.0, (and 15 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res                          : 0.15.1
   native-run (update available: 1.2.2) : 1.1.0

System:

   ios-sim : 8.0.2
   NodeJS  : v12.16.2 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm     : 6.14.4
   OS      : macOS Catalina
   Xcode   : Xcode 12.0.1 Build version 12A7300
```

- Linux development station (for reference)

```sh
⟩ ionic info

Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.11.8 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.3.3
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.1001.6
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 10.1.6
   @angular/cli                  : 10.1.6
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.3.3

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 10.0.0
   Cordova Platforms : android 9.0.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.3, (and 16 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res                          : not installed
   native-run (update available: 1.2.2) : 1.1.0

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/home/praetors/Android/Sdk/)
   NodeJS            : v12.13.0 (/home/praetors/.nvm/versions/node/v12.13.0/bin/node)
   npm               : 6.12.0
   OS                : Linux 4.19
```